# WooCommerce Product Category and City Based Shipping Fee

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

In a WooCommerce shop I have setup, a product category `'Bronx'` is a parent category and `'Baby Items Bronx'` is a child category of it. Here Parent category name **Bronx** is the city where the products under `'Baby Items Bronx'` are sold from.

Another product category `'Newark'` is a parent category and `'Baby Items Newark'` is a child category of it. Here Parent category name **Newark** is the city where the products under `'Baby Items Newark'` are sold from.

A customer from **Bronx** is trying to buy the products in `'Baby Items Newark'` category.

I am trying to set up a custom shipping fee in WooCommerce where it can calculate shipping fee based on customer's location and add a custom delivery fee. I was able to achieve to add the fee if the customer choose the city as **Bronx** in the billing address with this code.

```
function from_to_city_add_checkout_fee() {
    if (($_POST['city']=='Bronx')){
        WC()->cart->add_fee( 'Delivery Fee', 15 );
    }
```

Now I need a function that can calculate the fee if the customer is from **Bronx** and trying to buy products that is listed under parent category is `'Newark'`

I tried the following code and it does not work.

```
function from_to_city_add_checkout_fee() {
    if (($_POST['city']=='Bronx') && (has_term( array( 'baby-items-newark' ), 'product_cat' ))){
        WC()->cart->add_fee( 'Fee', 150 );
    }   
}
```

I tried doing something like this with the code snippet that I got from https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-check-product-category-cart/ that helps check what product category is in the cart, it still does not work.

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_cart', 'bbloomer_check_category_in_cart');
 
function bbloomer_check_category_in_cart() {
     
    // Set $cat_in_cart to false
    $cat_in_cart = false;
     
    // Loop through all products in the Cart        
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
     
        // If Cart has category "download", set $cat_in_cart to true
        if ( has_term( 'baby-items-newark', 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
            $cat_in_cart = true;
            break;
        }
    }
       
    // Do something if category "download" is in the Cart      
    if ( $cat_in_cart == true) {
     
    // For example, print a notice
    // Or maybe run your own function...
    function from_to_city_add_checkout_fee() {
        if (($_POST['city']=='Bronx')){
            WC()->cart->add_fee( 'Delivery Fee', 150 );
        }
    
     
    }
     
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the below code snippet.
and replace the if condition with your logic.

```
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'woocommerce_custom_surcharge', 10, 1);
function woocommerce_custom_surcharge($cart)
{
    global $woocommerce;

    if (is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX'))
        return;

    foreach ($cart->get_cart() as $cart_item) {
        $product = $cart_item['data'];
        if (
            $woocommerce->customer->get_shipping_city() == "Bronx" &&
            has_term('baby-items-newark', 'product_cat', $product->id)
        ) :
            WC()->cart->add_fee('Fee', 150);
        endif;
    }
}
```

You can get the parent category from

```
$parentcats = get_ancestors($product_cat_id, 'product_cat');
```

I'd rather create a shipping class and add it if the condition is true, so that a different shipping fee will be applied. 
Also it is easy when you use custom field for the city in products than category.

Comment: BTW, this needs to be replaced,  `$product->id` to `$product->get_id()` to prevent `id was called incorrectly` error_log warning.